# Prohibit external rest calls

Tags: java, rest

We are developing a webportal for our users. This webportal includes functions to find the users address. In the backend we use Java to provide a rest resource. Since we don´t want the user to login we wonder, how to secure this rest resource so no one else can use it.

Any suggestions, keywords or best practises?

Comment: If your users aren't logged in, and therefore could be anyone, who precisely does *"no one else"* cover?

Comment: We don´t want anyone else to use our address api except our users with our portal. I know that here is Cors but thats not save as I recall it. I wonder if you can generate some kind of token which identifies that the user is on our webportal and nowhere else.

Comment: What precisely does *"with our portal"* mean? If you're on some kind of intranet, then how can anyone outside that network access your site at all? Your question doesn't make much sense at the moment, please add more context.

Comment: Webportal should be clear enough. It´s the world wide WEB.

Answer (score 1):

Well one simple solution if you want to avoid logged in users is to use a header param with a secret value then it is a bit harder to break into the system.  This header is then sent from the webportal and read and validated by your backend system. And use https.

Comment: And if users aren't logged in, what prevents *anyone* from making a request and getting a secret?

Comment: I was merely pointing the OP to a possible solution, way toward a solution where they can secure their systems. Normally in a case like this if you have a backend you will have an access token/something that is validated. And "normally" you require users to login to the portal, however in this case I assume sooner or later they will add some security to the webportal or it may be that the web portal is hidden behind a firewall or something else. But you are obviously implying the correct thing, if the webportal is accessible from anywhere without security then the system is wide open.

Comment: In one of those cases the additional "security" is illusory, in the other unnecessary. The third the OP explicitly ruled out. That's my whole point; without meaningful context and a credible risk model, the question is simply not useful.